# Everytime I switch the current window to Pycharm, the Search Everywhere Box shows up

Tags: macos, pycharm

Everytime I switch the current window to Pycharm, the Search Everywhere Box shows up, no matter I focus the window on Pycharm by mouse or Command+Tab(Yes, the problem is on Mac OS).

I don't know if I have messed up the settings somehow, but it's really annoying.

Does anyone have any advices? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason myself.
I bought a Microsoft mouse and installed an drive software which is not matched to the mouse.
I uninstalled the software and everything works fine.